# Last Five Pages Visited Cookie with php+jquery

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

how to show Last Five Pages Visited Cookie with php jquery.

Comment: I made a job board based API indeed and simplyhired.
as you know both website can shown last query and how many job at the main page.

i need to know how they made it?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using PHP and jQuery, this can be accomplished solely with PHP:

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['history']))
    $_SESSION['history'] = array($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
else {
    $_SESSION['history'][] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if(count($_SESSION['history']) > 5)
        array_shift($_SESSION['history']);
}
```

`$_SESSION['history']` will be an array of URLs that the user has visited limited to 5.