# 5 last visited pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Hey everyone...
Im looking for a script that can generate a list of a users 5 last visited pages - I was thinking jQuery and Cookies? Anybody know where i can find a script like this ?

PHP/ASP is not an option!

Comment: Last visited where, on the current site?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Could those get your started?

[jQuery & Cookies (get/set/delete & a plugin)](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html)

[jquery.COOKIE](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)

Its sounds a bit tricky.

But could you create a serializable small queue object that maintains the **last 5 pages name and url etc**.

On every page, you de-serialize it, update and serialize it back, write to cookie.

Need to watch out for:

1.page load cycle

2.making a cookie too big it may get trimmed off the end.

Let other jquery+cookie experts to help you out.

---

Could those be helpful?

Or you have to do it with only jquery & cookies?

[let jquery know which was the last visited php page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855025/let-jquery-know-which-was-the-last-visited-php-page)

[Last Five Pages Visited Cookie with php+jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653604/last-five-pages-visited-cookie-with-phpjquery)

Comment: php and asp is not an option, has to be done with javascript/jquery only